# Unknown host exception when using spring data hadoop to connect to Cloudera QuickStart VM Hbase

Tags: hbase, spring-data-hadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I use [QuickStart VMs for CDH 5.3.x](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads/quickstart_vms/cdh-5-3-x.html)

I try to implement this [spring hadoop sample for hbase](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hadoop-samples/tree/master/hbase)

The sample from the host computer will connect to Hbase in the VM to create table, add data, read data.

In my pom i use

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.hadoop.version>2.1.2.RELEASE-cdh5</spring.hadoop.version>
    <hadoop.version>2.5.0-cdh5.3.0</hadoop.version>
    <hbase.version>0.98.6-cdh5.3.0</hbase.version>
</properties>
```

My hbase.propertise file:

```
hbase.zk.host=172.30.119.25
hbase.zk.port=2181
```

My application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:hdp="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd">

       <context:property-placeholder location="hbase.properties"/>

       <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.samples.hadoop.hbase"/>

       <hdp:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">
              fs.defaultFS=hdfs://172.30.119.25:8020
       </hdp:configuration>

       <hdp:hbase-configuration id="hbaseConfiguration" configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration" zk-quorum="${hbase.zk.host}" zk-port="${hbase.zk.port}"/>

       <bean id="hbaseTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate">
              <property name="configuration" ref="hbaseConfiguration"/>
       </bean>
</beans>
```

When run the sample i got this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=35, exceptions:
Wed Jul 15 16:01:24 ICT 2015, org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller@35988e16, java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: quickstart.cloudera
```

May someone help me solve this exception ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running client outside of a vm, try adding `quickstart.cloudera` and its external vm ip into `/etc/hosts`.

These vm's are not usually designed to be used from outside but cloudera's vm is a bit more friendly compared to hortonwork's vm.